# Describe how realtime database sdk is bandwidth conscious?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While learning firebase realtime database with flutter, I find out that the realtime database sdk is bandwidth conscious. Can anybody describe how it is bandwidth conscious with a proper example?

I have tried to find this answer but didn't find it till now.

Comment: What do you mean by "bandwidth conscious"?

Comment: I mean, why it uses less bandwidth while updating data?

Comment: "less bandwidth" than?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Local cache

Firebase caches parts of the database locally, to minimise the amount of traffic

#### 2. Minimal transfers on changes

If the database changes, only relevant parts are transmitted, not the whole database

#### 3. Data is compressed in transfer

Firebase uses data compression during transfer to minimise the traffic volume in bytes.

This sounds like a homework assignment. Best of luck!